# Find distinct inner objects in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We're trying to find distinct inner objects in Elasticsearch. This would be a minimum example for our case.
We're stuck with something like the following mapping (changing types or indices or adding new fields wouldn't be a problem, but the structure should remain as it is):

```
{
  "building": {
    "properties": {
      "street": {
        "type": "string",
        "store": "yes",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "house number": {
        "type": "string",
        "store": "yes",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "city": {
        "type": "string",
        "store": "yes",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "people": {
        "type": "object",
        "store": "yes",
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "properties": {
          "firstName": {
            "type": "string",
            "store": "yes",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "lastName": {
            "type": "string",
            "store": "yes",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Assuming we have this example data:

```
{
  "buildings": [
    {
      "street": "Baker Street",
      "house number": "221 B",
      "city": "London",
      "people": [
        {
          "firstName": "John",
          "lastName": "Doe"
        },
        {
          "firstName": "Jane",
          "lastName": "Doe"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "street": "Baker Street",
      "house number": "5",
      "city": "London",
      "people": [
        {
          "firstName": "John",
          "lastName": "Doe"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "street": "Garden Street",
      "house number": "1",
      "city": "London",
      "people": [
        {
          "firstName": "Jane",
          "lastName": "Smith"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When we query for the street "Baker Street" (and whatever additional options needed), we expect to get the following list:

```
[
    {
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Jane",
      "lastName": "Doe"
    }
]
```

The format does not matter too much, but we should be able to parse the first and last name. Just, as our actual data-set is much larger, we need the entries to be distinct.

We are using Elasticsearch 1.7.

Comment: people should be of type nested https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We finally solved our problem.

Our solution is (as we expected) a pre-calculated `people_all` field. But instead of using `copy_to` or `transform` we're just writing it as we are writing the other fields when importing our data. The field looks as follows:

```
"people": {
  "type": "nested",
  ..
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string",
      "store": "yes",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string",
      "store": "yes",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    },
    "people_all": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    }
  }
}
```

Please pay attention on the `"index": "not_analyzed"` at the `people_all` field. This is important to have complete buckets. If you don't use it, our example will return 3 buckets "john", "jane" and "doe".

After writing this new field we can run an aggragetion as follows:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "street": "Baker Street"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "people_distinct": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "people"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "people_all_distinct": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "people.people_all",
            "size": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And we return the following response:

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0.0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "people_distinct": {
      "doc_count": 3,
      "people_name_distinct": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "John Doe",
            "doc_count": 2
          },
          {
            "key": "Jane Doe",
            "doc_count": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Out of the buckets in the response we are now able to create the distinct people objects.

**Please let us know if there is a better way to reach our goal.**
Parsing the buckets is not an optimal solution and it would be more fancy to have the fields `firstName` and `lastName` in each bucket.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment your mapping of people should be of type `nested` rather than `object` as it could give unexpected results. You also need to reindex your data after that.

As for the question, You need to aggregate results based on your query.

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "street": "Baker Street"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_people": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "people",
        "size": 1000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please note that I have set `size` to 1000 inside aggregation, you might have to use bigger number to get all distinct people, ES returns only 10 results by default.

You could set the query `size` to 0 or use the parameter `search_type=count` if you are interested only in aggregated buckets.
You can read more about aggregations here. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html

I hope this helps!Let me know if this does not work out.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! Unfortunately this doesn't work (we tried with "object" and "nested"). We already tried to copy the people fields into a "people_all" field and use this new field in terms, but this didn't let to the expected result either. `{ 
    "aggs" : {
        "people_distinct" : {
            "nested" : {
                "path" : "people"
            },
            "aggs" : {
                "people_name_distinct" : { "terms" : { "field" : "people.people_all" } }
            }
        }
    }
}` in this case leads to 3 buckets: jane, john, doe

Comment: After searching for further information, we stumbled upon the not_analyzed field which should solve our problems. If `people_all` would be `not_analyzed` the buckets should be "Jane Doe" and "John Doe". But this doesn't seem to work. Is it because it's a nested field? I'll let you know, as far as I find more information. **Assumption:** This does not work because `people_full` is an array of strings.