# How can I fetch all disctinct objects within a field over an elasticsearch index?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to get all distinct objects from within a field over the whole index.

What I tried so far is:

```
POST http://es5server:9200/indexname/_search
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "size": "1",
  "aggs": {
    "tags": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "tags"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Currently this returns the following for me (I set size to 1 to include a sample document):

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 2,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "indexname",
        "_type": "news",
        "_id": "51",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "localized": {
            "de": {
              "title": null,
              "shorttext": null,
              "text": null
            },
            "en": {
              "title": "test new title",
              "shorttext": "hello my name is mayur and this is testnews text",
              "text": null
            }
          },
          "type": "object",
          "key": "testnews",
          "path": "\/",
          "tags": {
            "38": {
              "name": "I AM",
              "parent": "0"
            },
            "45": {
              "name": "ffddd",
              "parent": "43"
            },
            "43": {
              "name": "kkjjttdd",
              "parent": "0"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "tags": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": []
    }
  }
}
```

The buckets are empty, is this because the tags field contains objects and not text?

How can I get ES to return all distinct objects within the tags fields of all documents?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to have nested objects for you solution. See this question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33349315/find-distinct-inner-objects-in-elasticsearch)

Comment: more like a comment than an answer

Comment: That would still only return me a concentrated string for each object. I would like to have the objects as they are, as the person in the linked post would prefer as he stated.